# CSS / CSS3 Hierarchy

Tags: css

I have two different tags with different hierarchy but the same settings, is there any way in that case not to double my code? I tried mixing up the declarations but looks like only one of them will actually enjoy the traits..

```
section#leftSection nav#leftNav ul li a{
    background-color: #336b98;
    color: #EBEBEB;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

header#layout2_header nav#headerNav ul li a{
    background-color: #336b98;
    color: #EBEBEB;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use comma `,` to separates multiple selectors that have the same styles:

```
section#leftSection nav#leftNav ul li a, header#layout2_header nav#headerNav ul li a{
    background-color: #336b98;
    color: #EBEBEB;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: wow your fast.. great, my mistake was that:

Comment: section#leftSection,header#layout2_header nav#headerNav,nav#leftNav ul li a

Comment: You could also give your ul tags a class and just have `ul.classname li a` as the selector. This is a good solution anyway +1

Comment: Interesting, it gets very complex and yet so comportable.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the selectors with a comma , open the curly brackets add your code and hey presto...

```
section#leftSection nav#leftNav ul li a, 
header#layout2_header nav#headerNav ul li a{
    background-color: #336b98;
    color: #EBEBEB;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

It's good to keep each selector on it's own line to make your code more readable.